# primefaces inputText sometimes not updated

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I render a search mask from a model. One possible search mask input type is a 1 from n selection. This 1 from n type contains a `p:inputText` to show the selected value, a `p:commandButton` which opens a `p:overlayPanel` to select a value and another `p:commandButton` to clear the selected value.
In one situation the update of the clear button is not done. The ajax response does not contain the input field to update.
E. g. I have 3 of this 1 from n fields in the search mask. Choose a value for each works, clear each also works. When I assign for all a value and submit the form (executing the search) all is fine. Now I press on the clear button of 1 from n field no. 1 and value is cleared...fine. This also works for the 2nd field, but not for the last. How mentioned the update in the ajax response is missing, but the bean method is executed. Any idea? Or how can I debug it?
Code for the elements for a 1 from n field:

```
<ui:param name="curFieldSize" value="cc.attrs.curMaskElement.getSize()}" />
<ui:param name="curDummyCssClass" value="searchFieldChoiceDummyCssClass#{cc.attrs.curRowIndex}#{cc.attrs.curColumnIndex}" />

<p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.curMaskElement.propertyValue}" readonly="true" styleClass="#{curDummyCssClass}" size="#{curFieldSize}"
    rendered="#{curIsChoice and (curFieldSize gt 0)}">
    <f:converter converterId="choiceConverterSearchMask" />
</p:inputText>
<p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.curMaskElement.propertyValue}" readonly="true" styleClass="#{curDummyCssClass}"
    rendered="#{curIsChoice and (curFieldSize le 0)}">
    <f:converter converterId="choiceConverterSearchMask" />
</p:inputText>
<p:commandButton id="colChoiceSelectionButtonId" oncomplete="PF('choiceSelectionSearchVar').loadContents('#{component.clientId}');"
    immediate="true" actionListener="#{searchChoiceListController.setSelectedObject(cc.attrs.curMaskElement)}"
    process="@this" />
<p:commandButton immediate="true" actionListener="#{searchMaskBL.clearChoiceSelection(cc.attrs.curMaskElement)}" 
    update="@(.#{curDummyCssClass})" process="@this @(.#{curDummyCssClass})" />
```

There are 2 `p:inputText` because the model can define a variable size of a field or a fixed size. So defines the `size` attribute and one not. I haven't found a value for attribute size which is ignored in the same way by all browsers. Also I try to avoid JSTL. So I had to conditionally render the different `inputText`.
I am using Mojarra 2.2.10 and PF 5.2.6.

This is the rendered html for the command button to clear the input field:

```
<button id="searchInstancesFormId:j_idt261:1:j_idt263:1:j_idt265:colChoiceListSelectionButtonClearId" name="searchInstancesFormId:j_idt261:1:j_idt263:1:j_idt265:colChoiceListSelectionButtonClearId" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only removeChoiceValueButton" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;searchInstancesFormId:j_idt261:1:j_idt263:1:j_idt265:colChoiceListSelectionButtonClearId&quot;,u:&quot;@(.searchFieldChoiceDummyCssClass11)&quot;});return false;" title="Alle Werte entfernen" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c removeChoiceValueButtonIcon"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">ui-button</span></button>
```

This is the html of the input field:

```
<input id="searchInstancesFormId:j_idt261:1:j_idt263:1:j_idt265:choiceInputSizedId" name="searchInstancesFormId:j_idt261:1:j_idt263:1:j_idt265:choiceInputSizedId" type="text" value="Debitorisch" size="50" title="choice" readonly="readonly" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all searchMaskInputElement searchMaskInputChoiceElement searchFieldChoiceDummyCssClass11" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="true">
```

The update is done with the css class `@(.searchFieldChoiceDummyCssClass11)`. But I have really no clue why the last input field is not updated but all other before.

Edit: same behaviour if the update is done with id instead of css class

Comment: Solved it by clearing the input field with query.